# my socket connection from backend creating problem in rendring content in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

As i am trying to make real time text editor, where my socket connection in from node server and i am using `JoditEditor` for Rich Text Editor as the problem is whenever i try to type more than one word in editor my cursor gets reset and i have to click again on editor to write next one word as i want if i can write on editor continuously

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";
import { socket } from "../socketConfig";

function Msg(props) {
  const editor = useRef(null);
  const [message, setmessage] = useState(props.message);
  const [roomid, setroomid] = useState(props.roomid);
  const [sid, setsid] = useState([]);

  const configEditor = { readonly: false };

  const handleChange = (data) => {
    //sending message to above room
    socket.send(data, "ankit", roomid);
    socket.on("message", (data) => {
      console.log(data); 
      setmessage(data);
    });
    
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    //geting socket id for new user
    socket.on("newuser", (data) => {
      setsid(data);
      console.log("UC");
    });

  }, [message, roomid]);

  return (
    <>
      <h5>{message}</h5>
      <JoditEditor
        ref={editor}
        value={message}
        config={configEditor}
        tabIndex={1}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export { Msg };
```

[image: current what my app looks like]

Comment: Can you try putting this snippet in useEffect? ``` socket.on("message", (data) => { console.log(data); setmessage(data); }); ```

Comment: i tried the same before but its making no effect.. as same happening